Query outer join fixed values
I would like to query some IDs (fixed values) into a table, like a "outer join" with the mandatory fields should be the fixed values. I have to do the same for SQL Server and MySQL, but with one solution I could adapt it to the another. Example:
Table X:
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D

Fixed Values:
1
3
10

In this case, I would like to get some like:
1   A
3   C
10  null

My query should be something like:
Select ID, Name
From X
Where X.ID IN (1,3,10)(+)


If they are fixed, instead of hardcoding them you could put them in a lookup table.  So then you can update the list of IDs without a code change just a data change) and select where X.ID IN (Select ID from table)

I'm sorry, I forget to said that I can't insert them into a table because there I'm working into a production environment with restricted rules

Dreaming of even the simplest syntax between RDBMS is sometimes but a dream... Use the tools at your disposal in each RDBMS, don't limit both to neither.

If you can not put them in a table can you create a Stored Procedure and pass the values to the SP?  Otherwise the way you have it is probably going to be one of the only ways to do it if you cant update/create data in a table.

Yes, SQL is standardized. But every SQL database type has it's own dialect and variations from the standard. They are different enough that trying to support two different kinds of database with one common set of SQl will NOT end well. The datetime differences, especially, will get you, but also lateral joins, subtle differences on null handling, and much more.

You could use a derived table and then a UNION ALL to SELECT your arbitrary values:
SELECT DT.ID,
       YT.Name
FROM(SELECT 1 AS ID
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 AS ID
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 10 AS ID) DT
    LEFT JOIN YourTable YT ON DT.ID = YT.ID;

Honestly, however, use the tools you have at your disposal for each RDBMS. For SQL Server, a VALUES table construct is much simpler:
SELECT V.ID,
       YT.Name
FROM (VALUES(1),(3),(10)) V(ID)
     LEFT JOIN YourTable YT ON V.ID = YT.ID;

I'm not familiar with MySQL to comment if there's a more succinct version than the UNION ALL method.

MySQL also supports the VALUES statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/values.html. Old versions of MySQL don't, but they're no longer supported anyway.

That's for DML, @BillKarwin , it doesn't work as a construct elsewhere: db<>fiddle

ANSI-SQL anyway.

@ThomA MySQL's implementation requires the ROW keyword before each tuple. Cf. https://modern-sql.com/feature/values Also see examples and syntax reference in the MySQL manual page I linked to.

Which isn't the same as SQL Server's, @BillKarwin , so wouldn't work for a solution that can be used in both. It would, I admit, work for a bespoke solution, but your initial.comment implied, to me, that you were saying VALUES as used above would work.

Right — there are so many variations in SQL implementations that trying to develop one solution that works on multiple brands is honestly a waste of time. Just write adapters.

The MySQL table-value constructor requires preceding each item in the values clause with the row keyword, but otherwise can work much like SQL Server: FROM (VALUES row(1), row(3), row(10)) V(ID). But honestly, trying to support both MySQL and SQL Server with one set of SQL across an application is not gonna end well.

-- Using a CTE
WITH FixedValues AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
)
SELECT fv.ID, x.Name
FROM FixedValues fv
LEFT JOIN X x ON fv.ID = x.ID;

Alternatively, you can use a subquery directly in the FROM clause:
SELECT fv.ID, x.Name
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
) AS fv
LEFT JOIN X x ON fv.ID = x.ID;


You can use values statement for fixed values.
For SQL Server
Select n Id, Name
From TableX X
right join (values (1),(3),(10))t(n) on  x.id=n

For MySQL
Select column_0 Id,Name 
From TableX X
right join (values row(1) ,row(3), row(10))t on X.ID=t.column_0

fiddle
